# JWT token expiration check

Tags: java, jwt

I've a following utility class but whenever I check for an expired Token via verify method, it's not throwing the `JWtVerificationException`.

```
public class Token {

    private static String SECRET = "c3bff416-993f-4760-9275-132b00256944";

    public static String get(String name, String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return JWT.create()
                .withIssuer("auth0")
                .withClaim(name, value)
                .withClaim("random", String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()))
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))
                .sign(Algorithm.HMAC256(Token.SECRET));
    }

    public static DecodedJWT verify(String token) throws JWTVerificationException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(Token.SECRET))
                .withIssuer("auth0")
                .acceptExpiresAt(4)
                .build();

        return verifier.verify(token);
    }

}
```

As per the website https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt

> > When verifying a token the time validation occurs automatically, resulting in a `JWTVerificationException` being throw when the values are invalid.

**Edit:**

A case when client renewing token every 5 minutes, will following work or should I add few extra seconds to accommodate any network lag?

creates

```
.withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 60 * 1000))) // 5 minutes
```

verify

```
.acceptExpiresAt(5 * 60) // accept expiry of 5 minutes
```

Comment: How are you creating and passing the token. The `get` method creates token that expires 4 hours from creation time. The `verify` only checks if that expiration is past 4 seconds from the time `verify` method is called, which should pass if you are calling `get` and then `verify` without waiting in between.

Comment: It should be 4*1000 which is 4 seconds.

Comment: https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt says `.acceptExpiresAt(5)   //5 secs for exp`

Comment: Yes, `acceptExpiresAt` takes seconds your `Date` object takes milliseconds. Thats why you need to set JWT expiration time to `withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (4 * 1000)))` in order to expire it 4 seconds after creation time.

Comment: just for better understanding, are these services like facebook, twitter etc. use jwt tokens to manage multiple sessions across devices for each user? They seem to have no expiry as I continue to stay logged in for days.

Comment: I am not familiar with those services. But JWT tokens can be refreshed periodically.

Comment: See my edit please for a case when client is caching the token and renews every 5 minutes, while the token's life is for 5 minutes as well, do you see any problem with that?

Answer (score 5):

`JWT.create().withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 60 * 1000)))`
means you will create a token, which will expire after 5 minutes. It seems good.

`JWT.require(xxx).acceptExpiresAt(5 * 60)`
means you will accept a token which has **already expired** 5 minutes before.Even considering the network lag, 5 minutes of leeway is still too long. It should in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Just add separate catch block when verifying token

```
try {
 DecodedJWT decodedJWT = Token.verify();
 Map claims = decodedJWT.getClaims();

} catch (TokenExpiredException e) {
 // Token expired 
} catch (JWTVerificationException e) {
 // Token validation error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the token has an invalid signature or the Claim requirement is not met, a `JWTVerificationException` will raise.

When verifying a token the time validation occurs automatically, resulting in a `JWTVerificationException` being throw when the values are invalid. If any of the previous fields are missing they will not be considered in this validation.

Answer (score 0):

We can get **expire** **time** of a **JWT** with `.expiresAt` like this(in Unix Timestamp) :

```
val jwtExample = JWT("your string token")
jwtExample.expiresAt
```

Then we can define a `fun` for evaluating JWT like this :

```
private fun isJwtExpired(jwt: JWT): Boolean {
    val todayTime =
        (floor(Date(TimeUtil.getCurrentMillis()).time / 1000.0) * 1000).toLong()
    val pastToday = Date(todayTime)
    val expValid = jwt.expiresAt == null || !pastToday.after(jwt.expiresAt)

    return !expValid
}
```